# How should I change the username of or delete the admin user?

Tags: admin, users

I would like to either delete or change the username of the original administrator account created during the install of a WP 3.2 site. This is not possible via the admin interface (There is a message to say that usernames cannot be changed and the delete option is not available).

I have a requirement to change the username or delete the account. Is there a safe way to do this by editing the DB directly e.g. just edit the admin user row in the users table directly and alter the username?

Answer (score 1):

The safest way:

1. Create a *second* user account, and assign it to the **admin** user role.
2. Login as the user you just added
3. Modify the original admin account. Delete it, or (my preference, especially if the username is "admin") change the user role to **subscriber**